# .htaccess AcceptLanguage Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, multilingual

I´m having a website www.xxx.com which has english content. But if the user has german (de) as browser-language it should change automatically to german: www.xxx.com/de/. So I used mod-rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [R=301,L]
```

So this works, but it could be possible that the german user wants the english version and clicks on the english flag with the link to www.xxx.com. But then the mod-rewrite will redirect him to /de/ again.
So how is this possible?

And is it possible to save it to a cookie if the user switches language with flags?

Best regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

When the german user clicks on the english flag, set a cookie in the browser. For example, let the english flag point to a php script which sets a cookie and then redirects the user to the english version.

In the htaccess add a second condition, that will deactivate the rule.
You can test for cookie presence/value in the RewriteCond.